# CSS flex column-reverse ignores table width

Tags: css, flexbox

"table width 100%" and "td width xx%" not working with "tbody column-reverse". clue?

Fixed relative width for each cells in 100% width table is desired.

CSS only, please.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7gs1w7d/1/)

```
body { margin:0px; }
table { width:100%; }
tbody { display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse; background:#222; }
td.x { background-color:#eee; width:10%; }
td.y { background-color:#aaa; width:30%; }
td.z { background-color:#888; width:60%; }

<body>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td class="x">ax</td><td class="y">ay</td><td class="z">az</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="x">bxx</td><td class="y">by</td><td class="z">bzz</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="x">cxxx</td><td class="y">cyyy</td><td class="z">czzz</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `display: block;` to the td.x/y/z but it will stack like rows.
--Edit--
So that didn't work, but then i added display: flex; in tr tags and it's kinda responsive.

```
body { margin:0px; }
table { width:100%; }
tbody { display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse; background:#222; }
tr{ display: flex; }
td.x { background-color:#eee; width:10%; display: block; }
td.y { background-color:#aaa; width:30%; display: block; }
td.z { background-color:#888; width:60%; display: block;}
```

Comment: At this point I think you can remove the `display:block;` from the `<td>`'s

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:inline-block;` to your `<td>`'s

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4qq21n8/1/).

**UPDATE**

Here is a version that sets `display:flex;` to your rows, and you are able to have 10%, 30%, and 60% and remove the `display:inline-block;` style.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4qq21n8/2/)

Comment: I need to make the sum of the cells 100% (10% + 30% + 59% isn't good for me). But still, thanks for your reply.

Comment: So, tr {display:flex} was the key as Marks Kristiāns Ābele mentioned. Thx 4 update!